# changing passphrase on gpg subkey

Tags: pgp, gnupg, openpgp

Is it possible to change passphrase on a subkey by:

```
gpg --edit-key sub_key_id passwd
```

Or will this change the passphrase on the master key as well?

(My idea stems from the fact that master key is used only for certification and thus only rarely, while signing or encryption or authorization keys are of daily use and as such, less complex passphrase is desirable.)

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/879977/how-to-have-a-different-pass-phrase-for-a-gpg-subkey

Comment: @Anonymous Hmmm seems unfriendly from gpg part. What if I change the passphrase to the whole structure with master key and then delete the private key of the master key, keeping the master private key in a secure location with the old password. This would have the desired effect suggested at the last paragraph of my question, correct?